# Opening channel with whole wallet balance in LND

Tags: lightning-network-daemon

I was looking at help output of `lncli openchannel` and was wondering is there a way to open channel using whole current wallet balance, so that wallet balance minus opening transaction fee is commited to the channel? In c-lightning I can use `all` as a value for `satoshi` argument of `lightning-cli fundchannel` to do that.